# Fixing the number of columns in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have a 10X10 grid of buttons in my view.

I am using the collectionview to make this grid. I am trying to use Auto layout so that even when i change the orientation of my device the entire 10X10 grid is visible.

The way I am ensuring that it is a 10X10 grid is by calculating the button size based on the frame size. But if i use autolyout, I will not know the size of the view when I am populating the collection and hence I can set the button size to the correct size.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use Buttons Instead of Collection view and also use auto layout

See this tutorial if it helps
https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2